# Multiply two values if the word in the cell to the left matches

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have an excel sheet, this sheet has a list of Product and Quantity. Like this example:

Sheet 1

| A | B |
| --- | --- |
| String A | 1 |
| String B | 2 |

On another sheet I have a price matrix, like this:

Sheet 2

| A | B |
| --- | --- |
| String A | 0,005$ |
| String B | 0,1$ |

What I need to do is to calculate the total price based on the number of units of the product.

For that, I need an excel formula which, for example, locates the string in A1, e.g. String A, on sheet 1 and subsequently locates String A in the price matrix on sheet 2 and multiplies the quantity (B1 on sheet 1) by the price to the right (B1 on sheet 2) of the String A (on sheet 2) name in the price matrix.

Can you help me?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Hint: Check LOOKUP formula e.g. `VLOOKUP`, `XLOOKUP` or `INDEX+MATCH`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On Sheet1, using:

#### VLOOKUP

`=B1*VLOOKUP(A1;Sheet2!A:B;2;FALSE)`

#### INDEX MATCH

`=B1*INDEX(Sheet2!B:B;MATCH(Sheet1!A1;Sheet2!A:A;0))`